# Make AutoMapper recognize concrete type when mapping from interface

Tags: .net, automapper

I have a mapping like this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ISomething, ISomethingDto>();
```

I would like to configure AutoMapper to construct certain concrete types depending on the concrete type of the source instead of generating proxies.
E.g., I might have

```
class SomethingSpecial : ISomething {...}
```

and

```
class SomethingSpecialDto : ISomethingDto{...}
```

When I call

```
Mapper.Map<ISomething, ISomethingDto>(aSomethingSpecial);
```

I would like to receive an instance of SomethingSpecialDto and no proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up implementing an `ITypeConverter`, which checks the concrete type of `ResolutionContext.SourceValue` and returns the proper mapped type. This works, but it's not much better than implementing the mapping completely without AutoMapper.

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between `SomethingSpecial` and `SomethingSpecialDto`.
You will just have to map those concrete classes:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomethingSpecial, SomethingSpecialDto>(); 
Mapper.CreateMap<SomethingNormal, SomethingNormalDto>(); 
// ...
```

Comment: Yes, I actually tried that, but it's not sufficient. I still receive a proxy.

Comment: @EagleBeak: You need to remove the mapping of the interfaces.

Comment: Yeah, but then I'd have to cast my source to the concrete type before mapping. This is something I'd like to avoid. I imagined, I could somehow configure AutoMapper to recognize the concrete type and pick the appropriate mapping (which I of course would have to define as well).

Comment: @EagleBeak: Have you tried that? I am not sure you need to do this cast. (Honest question, I am really not sure about that :-) )

Comment: You don't need to cast. Just pass the concrete type as one of the parameters to Map (e.g. by calling GetType()). Check the method overloads

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm currently doing something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IAlpha, IAlpha>();

Mapper.Map<IAlpha, IAlpha>(alphaDAO, new AlphaDTO());
```

This *should* work with two different interfaces, as long as the properties match up, but I can't back that up with an actual test.

I'm not sure if you're trying to make AutoMapper know which object to create automatically, but I have a feeling that might not be an option.  At the very least, it would require that in the CreateMap method there be an additional parameter taking the concrete type that you'd like it to instantiate when it comes across that given Map, but it would be far too limiting.  In the end, you'd be better off just mapping the two concrete classes to each other.  Even if you map to AlphaDTO type, you can still return IAlpha.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a 1:1 between your objects and DTOs so no need to create maps against the interfaces.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomethingSpecial, SomethingSpecialDto>();
```

If you are dealing with interfaces during the mapping phase, the trick is pass the Type as a parameter to the mapping call:

```
public ISomethingDto DoMap(ISomething something)
{
   return (ISomethingDto) Mapper.Map(something, something.GetType(), typeof(SomethingSpecialDto));
}
```